# What species is this tree?

Tags: identification

It's the one in the center of this picture:
[image]

The leaves are this way:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is *Eucalyptus deglupta*, or Rainbow Eucalyptus.
It is native to the Philippines, Indonesia and Papua New Guinea. It is introduced to other areas & depending on where, may become invasive. A very pretty tree though!

https://assessment.ifas.ufl.edu/assessments/eucalyptus-deglupta/

[image]
[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucalyptus_deglupta